# STM32L4A6 - ISR is processed twice

Tags: stm32, interrupt

## Issue

I have an input signal that shall trigger an interrupt. The ISR then shall toggle an output pin 24 times.
Having it set up stright forward I am facing the issue that the ISR is executed twice.

## System

IDE: STM32CubeIDE v1.10.0
uC: STM32L4A6 (NUCLEO-L4A6ZG)
Pin config:

- PC12 (DATA_READY_NEG_EDGE) = External interrupt, falling edge (externally pulled down with 100k and 100n)
- PC11 (ADC_SPI_CLK) = Output

## Code

The auto code generator pulls out the following code

```c
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* EXTI line interrupt detected */
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != 0x00u)
  {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin);
  }
}
```

The callback function looks like this (but I don't think that this is part of the issue):

```c
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if(GPIO_Pin == DATA_READY_NEG_EDGE_Pin) // INT Source is pin PC12
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin); // Toggle LED

        for (int var = 0; var < 24; ++var)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(ADC_SPI_CLK_GPIO_Port, ADC_SPI_CLK_Pin);
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(ADC_SPI_CLK_GPIO_Port, ADC_SPI_CLK_Pin);
        }
    }
}
```

This way the interrupt is falsely triggered twice.
Interchange the sequence of "CLEAR" and "Callback" function call in the IRQHandler, the ISR is correctly only called once. But this is a hack and every time I generate the code it is reverted again, so for sure not a solution.

What issue do I have and what could be the workaround?

Thx for any support!

Comment: In theory, as far as I can tell, the order of callback and EXTI clear flag shouldn't matter. My first impression is that it's a debounce problem. If you run callback first, the callback function takes just enough time to debounce the input and only then clear EXTI event flag. Can you test this hypothesis of mine? Can you trigger that external pin with another GPIO, for example, to make it 100% clean interrupt trigger?

Comment: Eventually I have the same impression. I just added the interrupt clearing line also at the end of the ISR with which it now works (i.e. only executes once). Triggering that interrupt pin by hand (establish a negative flank using a wire connected to +3V3, connect it to the pin and remove it again) also makes the ISR only being executed once (unknow why ever this should be much better in respect of bouncing).
Thx for your response!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you did there. I meant triggering an interrupt entirely without physical intervention. Like if your PC12 is an interrupt pin, you connect PC12 to PC11 or something and just do GPIO output HIGH and then LOW on PC11 and see how program reacts to that. That way you rule out all sorts of bouncing for sure. Alternatively, every NVIC interrupt can be triggered with software (special NVIC function to invoke any interrupt, called software interrupt). Also, please add how exactly you clear flag at the end of ISR into the question, it's a vague statement